# bufferimage() in processing

Tags: save, byte, processing

I'm doing a sketch that gets part of the canvas:

```
PImage img = get(180, 0, 620, 400);
```

and the I want to upload this to my web server with these functions I had found:

http://wiki.processing.org/w/Saving_files_to_a_web-server

The thing is that when I try to call the function `saveToWeb_saveJPG()`, the function converts the `PImage` to a `Byte` array with `bufferImage()`, and processing says it does not exist. How could I convert the `PImage` variable to a `Byte` array?

Answer (score 0):

The method requires a byte array or `byte[]`. You can access this from your [PImage](http://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) img like this:

```
img.pixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this way:

```
PImage img = loadImage("file.ext");
byte[] toSave = new byte[img.width * img.height];
PImage.loadPixels();
for(int i = 0; i < img.width * img.height; i ++)
  toSave[i] = (byte)img.pixels[i];
img.updatePixels();
```

It doesn't present any issue, in compilation neither running!
I think it just work even though you can't open it as image if you save it as file!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to satisfies your question:

```
bufferImage(get(180, 0, 620, 400))
```

So your code will look similar to this:

```
saveToWeb_saveJPG("mytitle","savedJPG",bufferImage(get(180, 0, 620, 400)));
```